If a mother "forgot" her baby at the airport, will she be charged will child abandonment?
I recently saw an article1 that reports an astonishing situation: A mother forgot her baby at the airport, and boarded an international flight (bound for Malaysia) alone. The passenger realized that she had forgotten about her baby after they had already taken off, and, according to the article, "refuses to continue the flight", forcing the pilots to land. My question is mainly not about the pilot actions or aviation part, but the legal consequences the mother will face. Will she be charged with child abandonment? Does this situation constitute a parental neglect offense? Leaving a baby at the terminal is pretty dangerous, after all. I'm asking according to both United States and EU laws. Although this happened in Saudi Arabia, where laws may be different than the EU or United States, for the context of this question let's assume the same thing happened in the US or EU countries. What will happen? What legal consequences will the mother face? If not, why not? I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!
1: There are many, many more articles that mention such events. I digged-up tons of articles, news reports, and blogs on this and similar cases: another article reporting the same incident, and another more recent incident in which the couple was caught before boarding, gulf news article, cafemom.com/parenting, couple intentionally leaves behind baby at airport, 5 year-old left behind at airport (this one isn't as crazy, since the parents seemed to have noticed before they boarded the plane.).

@Jen Well, I would say I'm looking for whether this situation makes the mother eligible for being charged with child abandonment, so I guess your number two choice (whether this makes an offense). My question also have elements of your number three, i.e., can a parent be charged with child abandonment if the baby didn't suffer physical harm as a result? And also, can the parent waive off the offense by saying "they just forgot"? So I think it's number two and three. I'm not looking for a percentage of how likely the mother will be charged.

@LukeL if the parent's state of mind is relevant to the offense then the parent can make claims about her state of mind.  Nobody has to take those statements at face value, especially not the police, the prosecutor, nor the courts.  Waive is basically choosing not to enforce something or to assert a right, so the parent certainly has nothing to waive here.  Wave off is an unrelated concept that is occasionally misspelled because "wave" and "waive" are homonyms.

More likely an isolated instance of child neglect than "child abandonment" which generally denotes a sustained disregard for a child, not an isolated instance.

Also posted on SE Skeptics by another user. It would be very suprising if the flight had actually taken off before the loss was realised.

I think child abandonment charges might not be the only charges she'd be facing. Being a sufficiently unruly passenger that the plane needs to turn back is a crime, too.

No to criminal charges
australia new-south-wales
There are a number of crimes specifically related to the care of children in the NSW Crimes Act 1900 and similar provisions exist in all other jurisdictions.
However, all of them require intent or recklessness or allow for a reasonable excuse defence. Even were the other elements of the crimes made out, and that is by no means certain, a person who "forgot" may be negligent, but they are not reckless and likely have a reasonable excuse. Bearing in mind it is for the prosecution to prove what the defendant's state of mind was from the extrinsic evidence available. In circumstances where the person who raised the alarm was the defendant, it's going to be very hard to prove more than negligence.
Cases, where criminality has been engaged have involved knowingly leaving children in cars while paying for petrol, buying groceries or, egregiously, gambling. Now, we're talking recklessness.
Maybe to child protection intervention
Criminality aside, this event may be enough to trigger at least an investigation by the relevant child protection agency. The criteria there is the best interests of the child and whether state intervention is necessary to ensure health and welfare.

What is a "reasonable excuse" for forgetting your own baby? It's hard to imagine any excuse for leaving a baby out of sight, let alone getting onto the airplane without them.

@Barmar Bad memory? Tired? Sometimes you just forget stuff because you're running on automatic. Memory can work in weird ways. Doesn't mean that what you did wasn't bad, it just means you accidentally did something really stupid, which is different from deliberate abandonment, which likely would be illegal.

@kenod I guess my question is about the "reasonable" qualifier, but perhaps that's legal terminology that isn't interpreted the way we use it in the real world. Parents are expected to be extremely diligent when caring for a baby, and few would accept an "I was exhausted" excuse. Does anyone really think the parents were reasonable in the "Home Alone" movie?

@Barmar "few would accept an "I was exhausted" excuse"  I don't have kids, but my friends who are parents have told me that they all have "black secrets" of times when they almost accidentally did something unbelievably stupid, and put their child at risk. When they read about things like this incident they don't excuse it, but they do have a "there but for the grace of god, went I" moment. Humans are fallible, particularly when fatigued or stressed.

@CharlesE.Grant Right, we can understand how it could happen, but we don't excuse it, as the consequences are too dire.

@Barmar but we often have some space between "We don't excuse it" and "We criminally prosecute it".

@CharlesE.Grant I don't know how actual prosecutors would view this. I assume the mitigating factors might sway the court on punishment severity, but I hope they wouldn't just be let off. Some women have been exonerated due to post-partum mental illness, but just being exhausted is not so extreme (it's normal for all parents, and shouldn't be a get-out-of-jail-free card).
